# PHPmyAdmin not found in wampserver

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I was busy trying to make a multisite and changed some files within the WampServer. Now I cannot acces **phpmyadmin** anymore, it says:

*NOT FOUND: The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.*

I believe it is the httpd.conf file but I can't seem to find the problem... HELP would be much appriciated. I can access the localhost and see my local websites running.

These are the last lines in my apache error log:

```
[Tue Jan 17 12:39:59 2012] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jan 17 12:39:59 2012] [notice] Child 5148: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:00 2012] [notice] Child 5148: Released the start mutex 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:01 2012] [notice] Child 5148: All worker threads have exited. 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:01 2012] [notice] Child 5148: Child process is exiting 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:01 2012] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully. 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3032 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [notice] Child 3032: Child process is running 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [notice] Child 3032: Acquired the start mutex. 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [notice] Child 3032: Starting 64 worker threads. 
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:03 2012] [notice] Child 3032: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:05 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:06 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/phpmyadmin
[Tue Jan 17 12:40:07 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Same here! @developdaly did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in the new alias directories from the wamp panel
click on wamp tray icon>apache>alias directories>add new alias directory

try adding phpmyadmin folder as alias directory

I am also a beginner and I think this may help.